# Can a proton be trapped by eight other protons?

Tags: electrostatics

Q:

Eight protons are permanently fixed on the corners of a cube. There's a ninth proton floating at the centre of the cube. Is there an escape for the proton or is it trapped? Justify with a calculation.

I encountered this problem last semester and it just came back to me in my mind. And I don't know how to solve it. Could someone give the solution?

Comment: in a  completely, but completely symmetric system, it can sit there. In the middle in a metastable position, the slightest asymmetry, a cosmic muon passing through for example, will send it hurdling out, between the field lines against the interaction with the muon, accelerated as it is leaving.

Comment: The solution is to add up the eight 1/r potentials and to analyze the series expansion of the total potential at the center of the cube. The one dimensional problem has a weak potential minimum, and so does the two dimensional problem, if I am not mistaken, and I suspect that that's true for the three dimensional problem, too, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @CuriousOne I am just arguing from the symmetry of the problem.

Comment: @annav: you can't solve this one with a symmetry argument. He has to actually calculate the second (and I have a feeling even the third) derivatives of the potential and show that there is a stable minimum.

Comment: @CuriousOne for a metastable state one would need a complete solution

Comment: @annav: If the determinant of the Jacobian is positive, I believe, one is done proving that a finite stable region exists. I tried that, but it seems to be zero, so one has to go, at least, one order higher.

Answer (score 1):

Whether a charged particle is in equilibrium or not depends on its potential energy. A particle is in classical equilibrium when its potential energy is minimized (A consequence of this is that the net force on the particle becomes zero.). If you fiddle around with the position of the proton a bit you'll notice that the minimum potential energy the proton can achieve is not the potential energy at the center of the cubic arrangement.

The ninth proton is technically in a metastable equilibrium. It'll stay in equilibrium as long as it is perfectly stationary, and the slightest disturbance in its position would accelerate it in the direction of the disturbance.

One of the identifying factors of a stable equilibrium is that the particle in concern will return to its equilibrium position for extremely small displacements, which is not the case for the given proton arrangement!

From a Newtonian mechanics POV you cannot truly 'trap' a particle like you are implying. A particle can escape any given configuration if it is supplied with the right amount of KE!.

Comment: Pre-caffeinated question: is it thus the case that the center proton can move along a line which intersects the center of two opposing faces and oscillate along that line about the cube center?

Comment: The actual potential energy minimum for the proton would be non-local, and at infinity. This implies a meta stable case, and what you mention would be true for certain directions (such as the line joining two protons opposite to each other) of displacement but not all.